# PHPで、ある数字が特定の配列の値に含まれるかの判定を行いたい

Tags: php, laravel

PHP初心者です。

ある変数TestPosition
Aの配列Arrayに含まれる数値なら　A
同様に　Bの配列に含まれるなら　B
を返すような関数を作りたいと思っています。

下記のように `in_array` で判定できるかとテストを行ったのですが、エラーが出ます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Use of undefined constant A_CERTAIN_AREA_A_ARRAY - assumed 'A_CERTAIN_AREA_A_ARRAY' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

宣言しているのに undefined constant と言われるのがよくわかりません

また将来のphpのバージョンでは定数はエラーとして扱われてしまうのでしょうか？

```
class TEST {
    const A_CERTAIN_AREA_A_ARRAY = [1,11,13];
    const A_CERTAIN_AREA_B_ARRAY = [2,22,23];
    const A_CERTAIN_AREA_C_ARRAY = [3,23,53];

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $testPosition = 3;
        Log::debug(":"."テスト",in_array($testPosition, A_CERTAIN_AREA_A_ARRAY, true));
        return view('index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

クラス定数を参照するには定数名だけでは不十分です。
`self::A_CERTAIN_AREA_A_ARRAY` のようにしてクラスを特定してください。